# Api Response and Json laravel format

Tags: json, foreach, laravel-5.7

I'm using Laravel 5.7. and GuzzleHttp 6.0 to get API response 
from endpoint

I'm passing query data from Blade form to this function.

```
public static function prhmulti($multisearch, $start ,$end)

{   $city = $multisearch['city'];

  $client = new Client([
     'base_uri' =>  'https://avoindata.prh.fi/tr/',
     'query' => [
    'totalResults' => 'true',
    'maxResults' => '1000',
    'registeredOffice'=> $city,
    'companyForm'=>'OY',
    'companyRegistrationFrom'=>$start,
    'companyRegistrationTo'=>$end,
],
       'defaults'=>[
       'timeout'  => 2.0,
       'cookies' => true,
       'headers'  => [
         'content-type' => 'application/json',
         'User-Agent' =>"GuzzleHttp/Laravel-App-5.7, Copyright MikroMike"
       ]]]);

$res = $client->request('GET','v1');
$ResData = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents());
```

dd ($ResData) gives all data from API response.

But I am not able to return JSON back to other function

```
return $this->multisave($ResData);



public static function multisave (data $ResData)
```

This will parse JSON and

```
{
 foreach ($data->results as $company) {
    $name = $company->name;
    $Addr = $company->addresses;
    $businessId = $company->businessId;
    $companyForm = $company->companyForm;
    $registrationDate = $company->registrationDate;

  foreach ($company->addresses as $Addr) {
      $city = $Addr->city;
      $postcode = $Addr->postCode;
      $street = $Addr->street;
   }
 }
```

save data to Mysql.

```
$NewCompany = new Company();

 $NewCompany = Company::updateOrCreate($array,[
 [ 'vat_id', $businessId],
 [ 'name', $name],
 [ 'form',$companyForm],
 [ 'street', $Addr],
 [ 'postcode', $postcode],
 [ 'city', $city],
 [ 'regdate', $registrationDate],
 ]);

}
```

IF Parse part and Save part is inside same function code works ok(save only one company),

but I need to separate them because later on it's easier to maintain.

Error which I am getting to return $ResData

```
" Using $this when not in object context"
```

Information is in JSON array.

Also foreach part save ONLY one company ?

```
  foreach ($data->results as $company) {
  $name = $company->name;
  $Addr = $company->addresses;
  $businessId = $company->businessId;
  $companyForm = $company->companyForm;
  $registrationDate = $company->registrationDate;

foreach ($company->addresses as $Addr) {
   $city = $Addr->city;
   $postcode = $Addr->postCode;
   $street = $Addr->street;
 }
```

So : 1)  What is best way to create own function for parse JSON
         and other for save data to DB?
     2)  As foreach loop save only one company data, What is 
         best way to fix it?

Thanks MikroMike.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my own question for saving companies to db

- First get total number inside Array
- use for-loop to make counting
- use foreach-loop extract information per single company as object.

  ```
  $data = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents());
  $total = $data->totalResults;


  for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++){
  $NewCompany = new Company();

   foreach ($data->results as $company)
  {
   $name = $company->name;
   $businessId = $company->businessId;
   $companyForm = $company->companyForm;
   $registrationDate = $company->registrationDate;

  $array = [];
    Arr::set($array, 'vat_id', $businessId);
    Arr::set($array, 'name', $name );
    Arr::set($array, 'form', $companyForm);
    Arr::set($array, 'regdate', $registrationDate);

   $NewCompany = Company::updateOrCreate($array,[
  [ 'vat_id', $businessId],
  [ 'name', $name],
  [ 'form',$companyForm],
  [ 'regdate', $registrationDate],
  ]);


  }// END OF MAIN FOREACH
  }// END OF For loop
  }// END OF FUCNTION
  } // END OF CLASS
  ```